# navbar-fixed-top sticking to top

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i have designed a structure of a web page in which there is a topbar that comes on top and after that there is a slider and inside a slider there is a navbar!
now the thing is navbar should be sticky but what happens is when i add the class nabar-fixed-top it goes to the top and overlaps with the topbar let me show you with visual examples.

[image]

now this is how i want my web page to view now the issue!!!
[image]

when i add the class navbar-fixed-top is sticks to the top regardless of the content what i wan to do is when user scrolls down navbar should go to the top but when the user comes to top of the page again navbar should come back to the place as shown in the image 1 
here's my code

**html**

```
<div class="topbar">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <p class="marker">1880 Sismet Road Mississauga, ON L4W 1W9, Canada</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                <p class="phone">+1 905-212-9482</p>
                <span class="eye">+ -</span>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 padding">
                <Div class="float">
                    <p class="follow">Follow Us:</p>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Autombrakes/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Autombrakes/" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Autombrakes/" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Autombrakes/" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Autombrakes/" target="_blank"> <i class="fa fa-yelp" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="slider" id="height">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/navbar_logo.png" alt=""></a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/navbar_home.png" class="img-responsive"/></a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">EYE EDUCATION</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">FEMTO CATARACT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PROCEDURES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">DIAGNOSTICS</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/navbar_search.png" class="img-responsive"/></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" class="make-appointment">BOOK AN APPOINMENT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/navbar_list.png" class="img-responsive list"/></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#section1" class="scrollTo"><img src="images/navbar_downarrow.png" class="img-responsive downarrow"/></a>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.navbar .brand {
    max-height: 40px;
    overflow: visible;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
}
.navbar a.navbar-brand {
    padding: 9px 15px 8px;
}
.navbar{
    font-family: young;
    clear: both;
}
.navbar a{
    color: #515254;
}
.navbar-nav{
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}
#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1{
    float: left;
}
.nav > li > a:hover, .nav > li > a:focus{
    color: #007f3d;
    background: none;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: black;
}
.navbar-nav > li > a{
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.navbar-toggle {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.navbar-nav img.list{
    margin-top: -8px;
}
.slider{
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("../images/slider.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.slider img.downarrow{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 20px;
}
```

**jquery**

```
 $(window).scroll(function() { // check if scroll event happened
        if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) { // check if user scrolled more than 50 from top of the browser window
            $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("background-color", "#fff"); // if yes, then change the color of class "navbar-fixed-top" to white (#f8f8f8)
            $(".navbar-nav >li > a").css("color","black");
        } else {
            $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("background-color", "transparent"); // if not, change it back to transparent
            $(".navbar-nav > li > a").css("color", "#fff");
            $(".navbar").removeClass("nav-active");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did it myself using jquery what i did is i added the class navbar-fixed-top on scroll and removed the class navbar-fixed-top when it comes to top

```
$(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");

    /* effect for navbar change on scroll*/
    $(window).scroll(function() { // check if scroll event happened

    if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) { // check if user scrolled more than 50 from top of the browser window
       $(".navbar-nav >li > a").css("color","black");
        $(".navbar").addClass("navbar-fixed-top");
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("background-color", "#fff"); // if yes, then change the color of class "navbar-fixed-top" to white (#f8f8f8)


    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("background-color", "transparent"); // if not, change it back to transparent
        $(".navbar-nav > li > a").css("color", "#fff");
        $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-fixed-top");

    }
    });
```